# Converting Unix grep/sed/awk into Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, unix

Within our file structure we have snippets with tags. From my project directory, I want to return the snippet name based on the tag declared on the preceding line, for all files ending in `.feature` within the project.

For example, the directory contains a `login.feature` file with the following text:

```
@integration @unit @smoke
Scenario: Login to Product

@integration @unit
Scenario: Buy Stuff
```

The directory also contains a `logout.feature` file with the following text:

```
@test @wip @smoke
Scenario: Logout of Product
```

I want to run a single command that returns the following array:

```
["Login to Product", "Logout of Product"]
```

As you can see, I'm essentially doing the following:

```
grep -inr -A 1 '@smoke' ./my/directory | grep Scenario | sed -n -e 's/^.*Scenario: //p' | awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

...with the exception of converting the resulting lines into an array.

Is there an elegant way to do this in Ruby? Or can I somehow combine the Unix magic with Ruby sugar? Or should I stick to sed/awk/grep?

Comment: Nice use of sed/awk. Not sure there would be Ruby approach as concise and elegant as this one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with

```
results = []
Dir.glob("#{folder}/**/*.feature").each do |file|
  i = 0; line = nil
  File.foreach(file).map{ |l| line = i+1 if l[/@smoke/]; i+=1 }
  results << IO.readlines(file)[line].gsub(/Scenario:\s|\n/,'') unless line.nil?
end

p results
```

The Results:

```
["Login to Product", "Logout of Product"]
```

You can easily shift this into a method.

Edit: Updated this after re-examining your full command line. Looks like you only want the `Scenario` that comes AFTER a `@smoke` line and no other Scenarios should be included in the output.